# Apache2 cannot find sites after update

Tags: apache2

after I updated my server 1 hour ago to 14.04 LTS I can't find/load the sites hosted on that server.
I use apache2 and haven't really configured anything else than 2 enabled sites on it. As of now the site only shows all destinations as empty directories.

The sites are still on the server and looks to be intact but somehow unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same exactly happened to me. After looking into the /var/www directory, it turns out that now all the files have to be inside an html folder.

So the new path for your html files is:

```
/var/www/html/
```

Try to put some test.html inside first, just in case.